# Looping through a dataset - object-oriented approach

Tags: vb.net, oop, design-patterns

The problem is as follows, a group of users (~50k) must be filtered from a DB, four fields for each user must be saved into a variable, then a second process will take each user and proceed to enable some licences into another system/platform. Both processes will be developed into the same application.

My first attempt was basically a query looping through the users but I wonder if thinking in objects is a better approach.

I was thinking in a structure inside an object to hold the 4 parameters, then pass each user object to the other object however considering the amount of data I'm not sure if this is fine.

Thanks,

ps. newbie using vb.net and framework 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you read the dataset directly from DB then table columns will have the type of original table in DB,,, If some the filed's its bool, int string then no need to create objects from that dataset and you can make your filters using Data view and then pass this data view to the other process...

Comment: @your comment raised an idea on my head, the output of the first object can be a dataset. Thanks